# Using morphological operations for color images processing

Tags: image-processing, morphological-operations

Have you ever seen any articles about using morphological-like technique for denoising color images?

Comment: Have you find any?

Comment: Yep. Little busy right now. Will answer to this question lately

Comment: @Drazick sorry. i forgot about u. :( Yep there is pretty clear article in Journal of Electronic Imaging april 2011. "Morpgological opeartions on color images" Lloyd Sartor Arthur Weeks. Also simple split to 3 colos surfaces and process them separatly as gray-level images(Gonsales Woods.Morphological operations) - then unite - works well.

Comment: Do you have links? Thank You.

Comment: @Drazick email me to sergboec at yandex dot ru. ill send you links

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [this paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00797378/document) from Santiago Velasco, it's about Conditional Toggle Mapping, and it's application to denoising.